# Arduino Leonardo RX TX mystery

Tags: arduino-leonardo, hc-06

I'm at the tail end of a project using a Leonardo, a HC-06 bluetooth module and a few cell phone vibration motors.  Everything is working fine except the serial communication between the Leonardo and the HC-06.  I've done some tests to rule out common mistakes

1. TX is connected to RX, and vice versa.
2. Using a multimeter I checked for continuity with the RX TX, no problem there
3. I can upload the script
4. I uploaded the exact same script to an Uno, using the same HC-06.  I was able to connect to the HC-06 with my phone and execute the script.  So I know it's not the script and I know it's not the HC-06.
5. The Leonardo is working properly because I can upload the script and execute it using the Arduino Serial Monitor.

The only clue I have is that I can upload the script with the RX/TX connected and that's not supposed to work.  However, I checked the connections and there is continuity.  So I'm stumped.  The only thing I can think of is that I damaged the RX/TX while I was soldering, but I'm hoping it's not that.  Is there a way to test for that.  Any suggestions?

```
/*
 * created by Rui Santos, http://randomnerdtutorials.com
 * Bluetooth App - Turn On and Off LED
*/

#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(1, 0); // RX, TX

int led = 3;
int state;

void setup() {                
  // initialize the digital pin as an output.
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);     
  // initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available() > 0){     
      state = Serial.read();}

  if (state == '1') {
      digitalWrite(led, HIGH);}   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)

  else if (state == '2') {
      digitalWrite(led, LOW);}    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW

  delay(100);               // wait for 100ms

  //For debugging purpose
  //Serial.println(state);
}
```

Comment: You should read the Leonardo manual. All will be explained. It's very different from an Uno.

Comment: Why are you using software serial on pins 0 and 1?

Comment: On the Leo the RX and TX are labeled RX1 and TX0, so I assumed they were pins 0 and 1.  But I also deleted that line of code and tested it and still it didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Arduino Leonardo has native USB support. Which means that it has separate serial interfaces to the PC and to the hardware pins.

`Serial` is only used for the communication with the PC and is unrelated to the hardware serial pins 0 and 1. Those are exposed trough `Serial1`.

So, if you are using the exact same Uno sketch, that uses the hardware serial pins, it can't work on a Leonardo, because data is just sent-to/read-from the PC and not to the connected Bluetooth module connected on pins 0 an 1.

Comment: Thanks.  Any suggestions on how to change the script to reflect that difference?

Comment: You need to replace `Serial` with `Serial1`.

Comment: You're a genius gre_gor, it worked!!  Thanks for the help, I needlessly banged my head against the wall for 3 days.  Have a good one!